# How to format the element inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have three arrays for example:

```
var name = ["wheel", "rectangle", "moon"];
var type = ["car", "shape", "sky"];
var all = [];
var temp = " ";

for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    temp = name[i] + " " + type[i];
    all.push(temp);
}

for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    // I call here function to display all element of array `all`
}
```

The output is:

```
wheel car
rectangle shape
moon sky
```

But the format of output is not nice. I want to shift the element of array `type` before add them to array `all`, so I want the output to be like:

```
wheel       car
rectangle shape
moon        sky
```

My question is: how can I shift elements of the array to add them to another array and store them in a way that allows to me to display the elements like form above ?

Comment: What language is this? What does `string temp = " ";` mean? To answer your question, pad the first part out to some fixed number of spaces before concatenating it to the second. Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd.

Comment: by shift do you mean you want to add space before the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate which is the longest string in the first array so to know in advance how many spaces you need to append to correctly pad the string

```
var n = ["wheel", "rectangle", "moon"];
var t = ["car", "shape", "sky"];
var all = [];

/* sorting the values of the first array by length desc,
 * then get the length of the first element 
 */
var padding = n.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.length <= b.length;
})[0].length + 1; 

n.forEach(function(el, i) {
  all.push(el + " ".repeat(padding - el.length) + t[i]);
});
```

Output

```
"rectangle car"
"wheel     shape"
"moon      sky"
```

---

> [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbPEBQ?editors=0010#0)

Comment: The sort seems like an awkward way to do `Math.max(...n.map(s => s.length))`. Also, a sort comparator function is supposed to return +1/-1/0.

Answer (score 2):

> But the form of output not nice

If you simply want to format the output in a better way, then try `console.table`

```js
var name1 = [ "wheel","rectangle","moon" ];
var type = [ "car" , "shape", "sky"];
var all=[];
for (var i = 0; i< name1.length; i++)
{
      all.push({ name : name1[i], type: type[i] });
}
console.table(all);
```

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4mfjxr2/) to see the actual output since stack-snippet alters the behaviour of `console` api

Answer (score 1):

First loop over the array and find the max length. Then loop again and add spaces.

```
<script >
  var name=["wheel","rectangle","moon"];
  var type=["car","shape","sky"];
  var all=[];
  var i=0;
  var maxLength=0;

  string temp=" ";

  String.prototype.padLeft= function(len, c){
      var r = '';
      while(r.length < len) r += c;
      return s+r;
  }
  for (i = 0; i< name.length; i++)
  {
      maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, name[i].length+type[i].length+1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i< name.length; i++)
  {
      temp=name[i]+type[i].padLeft(maxLength-name[i].length-type[i].length);
      all.push(temp);
  }
 </script >
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do as follows;

```js
var id = ["wheel","rectangle","moon"],
  type = ["car","shape","sky"];
id.longestStringLength = Math.max(...id.map(s => s.length));
type.longestStringLength = Math.max(...type.map(s => s.length));
id = id.map((s,_,a) => s + " ".repeat(a.longestStringLength-s.length));
type = type.map((s,_,a) => " ".repeat(a.longestStringLength-s.length) + s);
console.log(id,type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\t` instead of space while concatenating to make it aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add tab '\t' and it will give you the desired output. Or you can append fixed number of spaces between the two array items.